# Probability density function needed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to know the probability density function of following variable $$z=\left|\frac{\mathbb{x}\mathbb{y}^H}{\|\mathbb{y}\|}\right|^2$$ where $\mathbb{x}$ is $1\times N$ vector with every entry being a complex Gaussian random variable, similarly $\mathbb{y}$ is a $1\times N$ vector with every entry being a complex Gaussian random variable. I will be very grateful if somebody provides a proof or some reference to the proof. Thanks in advance.

In the above $\mathbb{y}^H=\text{hermitian transpose of the vector}$, $||\mathbb{y}||=\sqrt{\mathbb{y}\mathbb{y}^H}$, $|p|$ is the magnitude of $p$.

My attempt:

We can write $z$ as follows $$z=\left|\frac{x_1y_1^*+x_2y_2^*+\cdots x_Ny_N^*}{\sqrt{\text{gamma random variable with parameters (N,1)}}}\right|^2$$ But how to proceed further? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: is $y^H$ the transpose of the matrix $y$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor its hermitian transpose. Meaning that first take transpose of the vector and then write the conjugate of every entry at its place. I have written this in my question also.